# How to add COM references in ASP.NET mvc 6 and Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can do that in Visual Studio 2012 w/o problems, but not in 2015 with MVC 6, pic related:

[image: Referecence manager in Visual Studio 2012 and 2015]

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I find your question interesting. DotNet application access to COM via interop assembly which can be generated with respect of [tlbimp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/697w37zd(v=vs.110).aspx) for example. Typically you have already generated a lot of such intreops. You can see there in `%SystemRoot%\assembly\GAC_MSIL` directory. For example I have Office installed on my computer. I will show below how to create small ASP.NET 5 project which starts Microsoft Word using the COM interface.

I created simple Console Application, have removed `"dnxcore50"` part from `"frameworks"`. Then I selected "References" in the Solution Explorer, clicked right mouse and chosen "Add Reference...". Now I clicked "Browse..." button

[image]

navigated to `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c`, chosen `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` and clicked "Add" button. After that, I could see the following view in Solution explorer:

[image]

It's important to mention, that `global.json` was modified and `"wrap"` directory was included in `"projects"` part. The folders `wrap` and `lib` was created in the solution

[image]

The folder `lib\dnx451` contains the copy of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll`. *Additional* `project.json` was created in `wrap\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` folder with the following content:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../lib/dnx451/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the main `project.json` contains now

```json
{
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I created the simple program which starts Microsoft Word and makes it visible:

```cs
namespace OldConsoleAppCom
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            wordApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

One can compile such application and successfully run.

Comment: Very interesting. Have you already tried something similar with the new dotnet cli?

Comment: @NicolasR: No I'm making a pause in my work on ASP.NET Core/5 after making unknown the release date of RC2 and the final release. I tried to follow ASP.NET 5 very active after publishing of RC1, but later, after a lot of changes and especially renaming of all packages, which broke existing code, I reduce my time invested in ASP.NET Core. Following the latest changes was too time expensive. I decide to make a pause till RC2. It will save a lot of my time in permanent adjustment of my code. I'm still waiting for the release date (see [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1333)).

Comment: @NicolasR: I hope too, but I hoped the same two month ago. Thus I decided for me to wait fill at least some new date for RC2 will be included in [the roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#schedule). I stopped my activity in ASP.NET Core till the time.