# Calling ADODB COM object from ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

Is it possible to call COM objects from ASP.NET 5/dnx.exe?  I've referenced a .NET 4.5.1 object that itself tries creating an ADODB Connection, and it fails with the following:

System.URI.FormatException: {"Invalid URI: The URI is empty."}

Call Stack:

```
System.dll!System.Uri.CreateThis(string uri, bool dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind)   Unknown
System.dll!System.Uri.Uri(string uriString) Unknown
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Design.RuntimeLicenseContext.GetLocalPath(string fileName) Unknown
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Design.RuntimeLicenseContext.GetSavedLicenseKey(System.Type type, System.Reflection.Assembly resourceAssembly) Unknown
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.LicenseInteropHelper.GetCurrentContextInfo(ref int fDesignTime, ref System.IntPtr bstrKey, System.RuntimeTypeHandle rth)    Unknown
```

Comment: If you have COM object then you have probably already .NET assembly in assembly cache `%SystemRoot%\assembly` or you can generate the generating an interop assembly by Visual Studio or `tlbimp.exe`. Is the assembly exist in GAC? I posted [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34530845/315935) which describe how to use `Word` for example from ASP.NET 5 application. It seems to me that it's the first step what you need to do.

Comment: @Oleg:  I tried adding a reference to ADODB.dll in the GAC to the ASP.NET console application directly.  The reference was added fine.  But I get the Invalid URI error when trying to create a new ADODB Connection.  So, I guess the problem isn't COM, it's specific to ADODB.

Comment: You wrote about COM Object which uses ADODB Connection. It has no sense to use ADODB Connection directly because one can use Entity Framework to work with SqlCommand, SqlReader and so on. What exactly you need? Can you just describe step by step instruction to reproduce the problem, which you really have?

Comment: We have a ton of legacy code that uses ADODB, it's not an option to switch to Entity Framework.  Simply create a .NET 4.5.1 class library, add a reference to ADODB, add code that tries to create a new ADODB Connection, create an ASP.NET 5 Console application, add a reference to the class library, calling the code from the class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this post, http://talk.remobjects.com/t/net-aspnet-5-uriformatexception-when-creating-connectionmanager/7589/2, it seems that the Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.dll assembly has no CodeBase property, and that is ultimately where the URI path is retrieved from.  I tried adding Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.dll to the GAC with the /r switch, to force the creation of a CodeBase:

C:\gacutil /f /i "C:\Program Files\DNX\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.dll" /r FILEPATH "C:\Program Files\DNX\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr.dll" "My App"

And it works!

EDIT:

I found the problem in the DNX source code that is the root cause of the issue.  I've submitted a pull request to fix the issue here:  https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/pull/3338